# Como fazer upload de imagem para a interface do Ckeditor?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ckeditor

Construi um pequeno blog com ajuda do **framework Laravel 5.3**. Na área de criação de posts estou utilizando o **Ckeditor**, mas estou com dificuldades para construir um "método/esquema" de upload eficiente.

Existem muitos plugins do próprio Ckeditor para essa finalidade, inclusive o CKFinder, porém, ou eles possuem licença comercial ou são ineficientes. Observei que o Wordpress parece utilizar o Ckeditor e utilizar um botão "método" próprio para fazer upload da imagem e posteriormente inserir dentro do editor as tags e links para a imagem.

> Alguém já passou por isso e poderia apontar alguma possível solução?
>   Por exemplo, como posso fazer um upload a parte via ajax e
>   posteriormente ter as tags e link inseridos dentro do editor?

Answer (score 1):

Eu passei por isso e tive que usar um addon do CKEditor, Image Browser: http://imagebrowser.maleck.org/

No site do CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/addon/imageuploader